# Второе тире? Запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, сказуемые

`А в таком случае Луна — спутник(,) (—) или Луна и Земля — двойная планета?`

Кажется, что если сказуемое *спутник* обособлено тире с одной стороны, то нужно обособить и с другой. А нужна ли выделенная запятая? Думаю, да.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*А в таком случае Луна — спутник — или Луна и Земля — двойная планета?

А в таком случае Луна — спутник, — или Луна и Земля — двойная планета?*

Эти варианты непонятны: три тире "плохо смотрятся", *спутник* как будто становится приложением или вставкой.
Думаю, лучше поставить только запятую:
*А в таком случае Луна — спутник, или Луна и Земля — двойная планета?*

Можно, наверное, разделить и на два предложения (в зависимости от контекста):
*А в таком случае Луна — спутник? Или Луна и Земля — двойная планета?*